# How can i convert MacBinary on windows platform?

Tags: macos

i need to develop or use a utility on windows platform 
to convert MacBinary2 to more readable type

any ideas?

Comment: MacBinary2 is just a container format; what's inside the MacBinary2 file? If it's something like a Word document, extracting it from MacBinary will get you something you can read; on the other hand, if it's a MacWrite or TeachText document, you have a much harder problem.

Answer (score 0):

Google "macbinary file format". MacBinary used to add 128 bytes with Mac-specific information at the start of the file, which you would need to remove. That's quite trivial. I really wonder where you managed to dig out MacBinary files.